# Fluid width for container of inline, non-wrapping elements

Tags: html, css, width, containers, fluid

I'm having a little CSS trouble.

I have some div elements structured like the following example.  There are a dynamic number of class="block" divs, each with a fixed width:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="block">text</div>
        <div class="block">text</div>
        <div class="block">text</div>
        <!-- More "block" divs here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

My goal is to find a CSS-based solution that will.

1. Display the `class="block"` divs inline, without them wrapping to new lines.
2. Support a variable number of `class="inner-container"` divs like the one above, each displayed as its own line.
3. Have the outer container fluidly `"shrink-wrap"` to match the width of its contents.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MNrkk) you go. Note that the width of the outer container's contents is by default 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but it might be a start:

http://jsfiddle.net/r4dEX/3/

By setting each `block` element to `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`, it should allow the elements to sit alongside each other, but not wrap to a new line if the content is longer than the available space (instead the `block` will move to a new line).

Each `inner-container` will display on its own line (`display: block` is default behaviour for a `div`).

Setting the outer container to `display: inline-block` will cause it to 'shrink wrap' to fit its content.

Comment: you might want to make outer container inline block as well, to fulfill the third requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy reply, but that isn't quite the solution I need... The class="block" divs in your example wrap when their width is too large.  I'd like them to remain inline without wrapping, regardless of their width or the width of the user's browser window.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MNrkk/2/) is an example where the blocks are inline, the inner-containers have a fixed width, and the outer-container is shrinking to fit.

Comment: Thank you for the very prompt reply, but that's not quite what I need.  I'd like the class="block" divs within a given inner-container to remain inline, side-by-side, regardless of how many their are.  Your example works fine when there are only a few, narrow class="block" divs, but those divs start wrapping if their are too many or if their fixed width is set too high.